# Cannot read property 'user' of undefined (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting `Cannot read property 'user' of undefined` even though the user is being created with no problem, when I hit register, it won't navigate me to the main page, I checked the routes and everything has the same name.
The Register.js where it's giving me the error:

> Register.js:50 TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'user' of undefined

Register.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import config from "../../config";
class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      credenciais: {
        email: "",
        password: ""
      }
    };
  }
  updateText(text, field) {
    let newCredenciais = Object.assign(this.state.credenciais);
    newCredenciais[field] = text;
    this.setState({
      credenciais: newCredenciais
    });
  }

  register() {
    fetch(config.baseUrl + "signup", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credenciais)
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(jsonResponse => {
        if (jsonResponse.confirmation === "success") {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("main");
        } else {
          throw new Error({
            message: "Algo ocorreu de errado, por favor tente novamente"
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100 + "%",
          width: 100 + "%",
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >

        <TextInput
          value={this.state.email}
          onChangeText={text => this.updateText(text, "email")}
          placeholder="Email"
          style={styles.input}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <TextInput
          autoCorrect={false}
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={text => this.updateText(text, "password")}
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Senha"
          style={styles.input}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.register();
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "rgb(80,166,255)" }}>Registrar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    width: 100 + "%",
    backgroundColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  }
});
export default Register;
```

And the api routes:

```
// Full Documentation - https://www.turbo360.co/docs
const turbo = require("turbo360")({ site_id: process.env.TURBO_APP_ID });
const vertex = require("vertex360")({ site_id: process.env.TURBO_APP_ID });
const router = vertex.router();

/*  This is a sample API route. */

router.get("/:resource", function(req, res) {
  const { resource } = req.params;
  const { query } = req;
  turbo
    .fetch(resource, query)
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "success",
        data: data
      });
      return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "fail",
        message: "Sorry, something went wrong"
      });
      return;
    });
});

router.post("/signup", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  turbo
    .createUser(req.body)
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "success",
        data: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "fail",
        message: err.message
      });
    });
});

router.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  turbo
    .login(req.body)
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "success",
        data: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "fail",
        message: err.message
      });
    });
});

router.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  turbo
    .login(req.body)
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "success",
        data: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "fail",
        message: err.message
      });
    });
});

router.get("/users/:id/photo", function(req, res) {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.params);
  const myPhoto = {
    url: req.body.imageUrl,
    user: req.params.id
  };
  turbo
    .create("photo", myPhoto)
    .then(data => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "success",
        data: data
      });
      return;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "fail",
        message: "Sorry, something went wrong"
      });
      return;
    });
});

router.post("/users/:id/photo", function(req, res) {
  const userId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.params);
  const myPhoto = {
    url: req.body.imageUrl,
    user: req.params.id
  };
  turbo
    .create("photo", myPhoto)
    .then(resp => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "success",
        data: resp
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json({
        confirmation: "fail",
        err: err
      });
    });
});

router.get("/:resource/:id", function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    confirmation: "success",
    resource: req.params.resource,
    id: req.params.id,
    query: req.query // from the url query string
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The weird part of all of this is that it's still registering and saving the user data, I can then reload the app and just login with the details that gave me that error.
I'm using react-native, turbo360 as the api, and react-navigation

Comment: it's probably your `createUser` method on the API that's getting that error, but without seeing that method body it's hard to tell why it'd give you that error. If you can set a debug breakpoint on that method then you can probably tell more about why it's failing. Also I noticed a spelling error: `credentials`  ;)

Comment: without knowing anything about turbo, I'd guess you need to convert `req.body` to an object via `JSON.parse(req.body)`, i.e. `turbo.createUser(JSON.parse(req.body))`

Comment: @riqitang credenciais is actually just the portuguese word for credentials, i have the "body: JSON.stringify(this.state.credenciais)", i thought this would work, i'll be trying json.parse in the api

Comment: Okay, tried parsing using the JSON.parse and it doesn't get to the point where it registers anymore

Comment: Use debugger to identify at which part you are getting this error, as without knowing input and output of each function it's hard to tell what went wrong. Also You don't need to parse if input is parsed, or stringify if input is already a string, check what you are getting in input it's data type and then see if you need JSON.parse or not, just trying bunch of code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NAVIN i tried using the console to log every step, from what i understood, it sent the message to the api, but when it gets to this point: ".then(jsonResponse =>" it simply says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined", but it doesn't even get to the point where i have a catch error message

Comment: If you're controlling the API you should be able to set a breakpoint in the API and look at how it's handling the request. It'll make your life much easier to figure out how to do that. What IDE are you using to run the API?

Comment: did you `console.log(jsonResponse)`, what was output. What did `response.json()` did. also I think problem is here `.then(response => response.json())` you called a function and thought will return something when it's not returning. `.then(argument)` argument only get value which is returned from impervious function. need to `.then(response => return response.json())`.

Comment: @NAVIN i think that you're correct, since i've been logging the response and it returns "Response(bodyInit, options) {
      if (!options) {
        options = {};
      }

      this.type = 'default';
      this.status = options.status === undefined ? 200 : options.status;
      this.ok …" in the console, but why is it returning undefined? I'm using it inside .then after fetch how would i be able to take the value that is fetched?

Comment: use `console.log(response.json())` and `console.log(response.json)` check what they both give. What I was trying to convey is `a().then( r1 => { return "Hello";}).then( r2 => {console.log(r2);})`, r1 will have value that `a()` will return and `r2` will have value that previous then returned, here its `Hello`. Thus check what `response.json()` return. also in `.then(response => response.json())` you are just calling a function not returning.

Comment: @NAVIN response.json() says that it's not a function, when i stringify it, it returns everything normal, it seems that the error is right here ".then(response => response.json())", what is weird is that it used to navigate to the main screen normally and wouldn't throw me this error, instead, it just stays in the register screen and doesn't change